# Axios has become Unhandled promise rejection with ie9

Tags: vue.js, axios

Axios has become Unhandled promise rejection with ie9, and 'Babel-polyfill' didn't help either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular How do I ask a good question? and What topics can I ask about here?. From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Hey! Please copy your console log from your browser with the error and post the code where you making your promise. Greetings